# Delphi Cannot change this property when using LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

Can anybody explain to me what the error message "*Cannot change this property when using LiveBindings*" is telling me?

I am new to FMX / Live Bindings and I had something working, but I changed a few things and now, I am getting this error when trying to bind the fields of a TFDMemTable to a TGrid.

I had the same fields from the same table bound to the grid before!

Comment: I assume that you are attempting to set up your LiveBindings using the LiveBindings editor in the IDE rather than in code.  There's nothing wrong with that, except that it makes it difficult for you to convey to us readers exactly what it is that you are doing which provokes the error.  I've not come across the exact error message you quote, so don't now how to reproduce your problem atm.  The best I can suggest to work around that is if you could edit your q, please, to copy & paste the contents of your form's .DFM file into it.

Comment: It would also help if you can tell us which properties are you binding by using LiveBindings. Also make sure that you are perhaps not trying to modify a read only property of TFDMemTable. It is easy to make mistake by starting binding connection from wrong component (start binding from TGrid to TFDMemTable instead the way around).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just encountered the same thing and this was the only reference to this error I could find. After playing around with my LiveBindings for a bit and trying different things, not being able to save the form, I went searching through the Delphi source for that error message and found it to only be raised for TCustomGrid components.

I was indeed using a TCustomGrid descendent, TGrid, and as soon as I removed it, the error stopped happening. Thinking it had simply been hooked up wrong somehow, I re-added it but immediately started getting the error again.

Replacing it with a TStringGrid was the solution for me.